# Rails iterate over create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have this project and I just don't know how to get it to work.

So this project is a replica of [CS:GO Jackpot](https://csgojackpot.com/). I would like to iterate over the create method to create the given number of tickets. In my mind it looks something like this

```
#views/_form.html.erb

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.number_field :number %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit %>

 #tickets_controller.rb
   def create
     @repeat = params[:number]

     @repeat.times do
       @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change it to the following because Ticket.new will not save the created object.

```
@repeat.times.each{Ticket.create(ticket_params)}
```

Also, where is ticket_params coming from? Strong Parameters I am guessing? You will have to define that as well.

Comment: Yep, ticket_params is coming from Strong Parameters. I have it defined because I used scaffolding to generate everything.

I have another question, how useful would it be, if I use the Range object instead of creating millions of records? It would be something like this:

first person has a range from 1-10,
second person has a range from 11-432
third person has a range from 433-547 etc.
And then use the random number generator to pick one person?

Oh and thanks for the advice!

Comment: If there will be hundreds of tickets assigned to a specific person it would dramatically reduce the amount of database rows which is almost always a good thing. I guess it depends on whether you need to store additional data which varies between tickets.

Comment: I am going to try both and test and play around with them a little to see which one is better. Thanks for your knowledge and time @errata